# Complex std::map, structure, std::deque problem

Tags: c++, c++14

My objective is to have an ordered map of timeframes (it's for timeseries data analysis), indexed via a vector (as I sometimes need to reference the structure sequentially and not via the map key), with references to the OHLCCandle structure and having the resulting data presented via the deque.

Data access will be like: `data_[5].get().open[0]` meaning accessing the 5 min timeframe retrieving the open data at shift 0 or as another example, `data_[15].get().close[4]` meaning accessing the 15 min timeframe retrieving the close data at shift 4 (0 being the most recent).

My code so far is:

```
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Price>
struct OHLCCandle final
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<Price>::value, "");

    using Container = std::deque<Price>;

    Container open;
    Container high;
    Container low;
    Container close;
};

using Candle = OHLCCandle<double>;
using CandleContainer = std::vector<Candle>;
using Timeframe = int;

std::map<Timeframe, std::reference_wrapper<Candle>> data_;

auto emplace(const int timeframe, const Candle& candle) -> decltype(auto)
{
    auto error = int{ 0 };
    try
    {
        //////// Problem area begin
        auto candles = CandleContainer{};
        candles.push_back(candle);

        const auto pair = data_.emplace(std::make_pair(timeframe, candles));
        //////// Problem area end

        if (!pair.second)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Emplacement failed, doing nothing. timeframe = " << timeframe << std::endl;
            error = (std::numeric_limits<int>::min)();
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Unknown error occured, ignoring. timeframe = " << timeframe << ", erc = " << e.what() << std::endl;
        error = (std::numeric_limits<int>::min)();
    }

    return error;
};
```

But, I'm unsure how to construct the CandleContainer structure so that it can be combined with the `std::map` part of the code and I'm receiving the following errors under godbolt.org (code is godbolt.org ready! - `https://godbolt.org/z/d9HByG`):

```
[x64 msvc v19.22 #1] note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::emplace<std::pair<int,std::vector<Candle,std::allocator<OHLCCandle<double>>>>>(std::pair<int,std::vector<Candle,std::allocator<OHLCCandle<double>>>> &&)' being compiled
[x64 msvc v19.22 #1] note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>>,bool> std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::emplace<std::pair<int,std::vector<Candle,std::allocator<OHLCCandle<double>>>>>(std::pair<int,std::vector<Candle,std::allocator<OHLCCandle<double>>>> &&)' being compiled
```

What do I need to do to achieve my objectives and resolve the compilation errors?

Thanks.

Comment: You have copied the additional information from the error, but not the error itself. What is it?

Comment: The "errors" you listed are two notes (telling you where the error happened) that do not contain an actual error. Not a real issue because you have the MCVE, just for the record.

Comment: The errors I've highlight are godbolt reported errors (no more errors are produced). In VS, the error for the same code is: 
Error C2665 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: You're using `-> decltype(auto)`, so I have retagged your question as C++14.

Comment: @Andrew Why don't you add the godbolt link that you are looking at? Then we don't have to figure out which flags you use and so on :)

Comment: @MaxLanghof I didn't know if that was allowed but I'll chance it!

Comment: @Andrew please do! Online compilers are super useful, and having an MCVE to tinker with in one click is the best thing for answerers.

Comment: @quentin done as requested

Comment: @Andrew I've seen people remove them because "link rot" but if your question is complete even without it then it's just nice to have for readers. You at least have my full support, for what that's worth. Looking at the link, there are only two _blue_ lines, but there are certainly more lines (and it's only those other ones that contain the all-important word "error" - in this case, the first one).

Comment: It looks to me like you're simply trying to insert `candles`, a `std::vector<Candle>`, inside the value of a map which expects a `Candle &`. The error is laughably convoluted, but quite legitimate.

Comment: Well, `std::deque` is pretty much a useless container because it is not contiguous and and creating an empty `std::deque` allocates 608 bytes (with GNU C++ standard library). You may like to simplify your design and throw away `map` and `deque`.

Answer (score 0):

Someone helped me out, thanks very much to them.

The solution is as follows:

```
#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

template<typename Price>
struct OHLCCandle final
{
    static_assert(std::is_floating_point<Price>::value, "");

    using Container = std::deque<Price>;

    Container open;
    Container high;
    Container low;
    Container close;
};

using Candle = OHLCCandle<double>;
using CandleContainer = std::vector<Candle>;
using Timeframe = int;

std::map<Timeframe, std::reference_wrapper<Candle>> data_;
CandleContainer candles_;

auto emplace(const int timeframe, const Candle& candle) -> decltype(auto)
{
    auto error = int{ 0 };
    try
    {
        candles_.push_back(candle);
        const auto pair = data_.emplace(std::make_pair(timeframe, std::ref(candles_.back())));

        if (!pair.second)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR: Emplacement failed, doing nothing. timeframe = " << timeframe << std::endl;
            error = (std::numeric_limits<int>::min)();
        }
    }
    catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "ERROR: Unknown error occured, ignoring. timeframe = " << timeframe << ", erc = " << e.what() << std::endl;
        error = (std::numeric_limits<int>::min)();
    }

    return error;
};
```

Thanks to all who made suggestions.